# Invalid Form Body in Discord.js ban command

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

So, i have been trying to make a ban command. I basically used the same system on a kick command, but here it didnt work and just gave me an error. I am confused since in the error it doesnt display a line of code or something.
My Command / Code:

```js
module.exports = {
    name: 'ban',
    description: "Ban Command.",
    execute(msg, args){
    const Discord = require('discord.js')
    const Embeds = require('./../embed')
    let perms = msg.member.permissions  
    let has_kick = perms.has("BAN_MEMBERS")
    if (has_kick === true) {
        const toban = msg.mentions.members.first()
        delete args[0]
        var string = args.join(' ')
        Embeds.error(toban, `You have been banned from ${msg.guild.name} by the user ${msg.author} with the reason ${string}`)
        setTimeout(function(){ 
            try {
            toban.ban(`was banned by ${msg.author} for: ${string}`)
            Embeds.kicked(msg.channel, `${toban} has been banned by ${msg.author} from the server with the following reason: ${string}`, `Banned User from the server`)
            } catch {
                Embeds.error(msg.channel, `I dont have permissions to ban ${toban} `, "Error")
            }
         }, 1000); 
    } else {
        const toban = msg.mentions.members.first()
        Embeds.error(msg.channel, `You dont have permissions to Ban ${toban} `, "Error")
    }
}
}
```

The Error:

```
(node:13896) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: DiscordAPIError: Invalid Form Body
DICT_TYPE_CONVERT: Only dictionaries may be used in a DictType
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is pretty easy to solve, all you have to to is pass the right amount of Parameters in the right way to the `.ban` function.

```
.ban({ days: 7, reason: 'your reason here' })
```

https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=ban

Comment: if i wana ban someone for 20 days ?

Comment: set `days` to 20