# Invalid Form Body - Discord.js ban command

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I'm attempting to make a ban command, printing the information in an embed, however whenever I attempt to execute the command, it gives me an error, and I'm not sure how to fix it.

Here's my code:

```
    if(command === "ban") {
if(!message.member.roles.cache.some(r=>["role"].includes(r.name)))
return message.reply("You do not have permissions to use this command. ``(MOD PERMS)``");
let member = message.mentions.members.first();
if(!member)
return message.reply("Please mention a valid member of this server.");
if(!member.bannable) 
return message.reply("I am unable to ban this user.");
let reason = args.slice(1).join(' ');
if(!reason) reason = "No reason provided";
await member.ban(reason)
.catch(error => message.reply(`Sorry ${message.author} I couldn't ban because of : ${error}`));
const user = message.mentions.users.first()
const embedmessage = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
.setColor(`RANDOM`)
.setTitle("User was Banned")
.setAuthor(`Moderator: ${message.author.tag}`)
.setDescription(`Banned user: ${member.user.tag}`)
.addFields(
    { name: 'Reason for ban:', value: `${reason}`}
)
.setThumbnail(user.displayAvatarURL());
message.channel.send(embedmessage)
}
```

Here's the error that it shows:

```
DiscordAPIError: Invalid Form Body
DICT_TYPE_CONVERT: Only dictionaries may be used in a DictType
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Invalid Form Body in Discord.js ban command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64297816/invalid-form-body-in-discord-js-ban-command)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The docs for [`<GuildMember.ban()>`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=ban), state that the options you can provide should be an options object.

so change your code to

```
await member.ban({reason: reason})
```