# Discord.js ban command ban reason

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

Im trying to get a ban command and im using my pervious kick command as a sort of template, i cant quite get the ban reason to work, im assuming thats the only issue the code is below.

```
const Discord = require('discord.js')


module.exports.run = async (bot, message, args) => {

  if (!message.member.hasPermission('BAN_MEMBERS')) return message.reply('**No permission**') 
  const user = message.mentions.users.first();

    if (user) {
      const member = message.guild.member(user);
      
      if (member) {
        member
          .ban('no reason')
          .then(() => {
            message.channel.send(`${user.tag} Has been banned`)
          })
          .catch(err => {
            message.reply('Unable');
            console.error(err);
          });

      } else {
        message.reply("Error");
      }
    } else {
      message.reply("You forgot to mention someone");
    }
};

  module.exports.help = {
    name: "ban"
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You must supply the correct parameters for `.ban()`

in this case `.ban({reason: 'no reason'})`

so your corrected code is

```
if (!message.member.hasPermission("BAN_MEMBERS"))
  return message.reply("**No permission**");
const user = message.mentions.users.first();

if (user) {
  const member = message.guild.member(user);

  if (member) {
    member
      .ban({ reason: "no reason" })
      .then(() => {
        message.channel.send(`${user.tag} Has been banned`);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        message.reply("Unable");
        console.error(err);
      });
  } else {
    message.reply("Error");
  }
} else {
  message.reply("You forgot to mention someone");
}
```

also, please supply errors in future and look for [Other information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64297816/invalid-form-body-in-discord-js-ban-command) beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

Adding on, a lot of that will not work in V13

```
if (!message.member.permissions.has("BAN_MEMBERS"))
  return message.reply("**You do not have the proper permissions.**");
const user = message.mentions.users.first();

if (user) {
  const member = message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id);

  if (member) {
    member
      .ban({ reason: "no reason" })
      .then(() => {
        message.channel.send(`${user.tag} Has been banned`);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        message.reply(`Unable to ban User. \`\`\`${err}\`\`\` `);
        console.error(err);
      });
  } else {
    message.reply("Error");
  }
} else {
  message.reply("You forgot to mention someone, <@${message.author.id}>");
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```js
 // © Ahmed1Dev
 
const Discord = require('discord.js')


module.exports.run = async (bot, message, args) => {

  if (!message.member.hasPermission('BAN_MEMBERS')) return message.reply('**No permission**') 
  const user = message.mentions.users.first();

  let reason = args.slice(2).join(' '); 

    if (user) {
      const member = message.guild.member(user);
      
      if (member) {
        member
          .ban('no reason')
          .then(() => {
            message.channel.send(`${user.tag} Has been banned`)
          })
          .catch(err => {
            message.reply('Unable');
            console.error(err);
          });

      } else {
        message.reply("Error");
      }
    } else {
      message.reply("You forgot to mention someone");
    }
};

  module.exports.help = {
    name: "ban"
  }
// © Ahmed1Dev
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).